# Infinite run time

Tags: c++

For the code below in Ubuntu 16.04

For custom testcase

4 3

1 2 3 7

My runtime is infinite and there is no output. (No output means that 'a' is also not printed on console). However when I comment the function call foo

```
// int temp = foo(ab, 0, n-1);
```

I get output

a##

What can be the reason of infinite run time and no output that I am missing?

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int a[1000000];

int foo(int x, int f, int l)
{
    int m = (f+l)/2;
    while(f<=l)
    {
        if(a[m]==x)
            return 1;
        else if(a[m]<x)
            f = m+1;
        else if(a[m]>x)
            l = m-1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int n, x;
    cin >> n;
    cin >> x;
    int i=0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> a[i];
    }
    cout<<'a';
    sort(a,a+n);
    for(i=0; i<n-1; i++)
    {
        if(a[i]==a[i+1])
        {
            cout << 0;
            return 0;
        }
    }
    cout<<'#';

    int ab = a[i];
    int temp = foo(ab, 0, n-1);
    cout<<'#';
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you're not getting any output (not even the `'a'`) is that `stdout` is buffered. Typically it is line-buffered, meaning it will only be printed when a new line is written.

You can force whatever's in the buffer to print out immediately by doing `std::cout << std::flush;`, or for example in your case, `std::cout << 'a' << std::flush;` would work.

Answer (score 0):

The reason of infinite loop is that your `f` and `l` values are updated at most once. initially `m` points to the middle of array (i.e. `(n-1)/2`) and from that moment,
-if the element `a[m]` is less than `x`, you infinitely assign `m+1` i.e. `(n-1)/2 + 1`to `f`
-if the element `a[m]` is larger than `x`, you infinitely assign `(n-1)/2 - 1` to `l`

In either case, `f` never gets larger than `l` and `l` never gets smaller than `f` (unless array has a single element or it has two elements and `x<a[0]`)

Try updating the function in the following way:

```
int foo(int x, int f, int l)
{
    int m = (f+l)/2;
    while(f<=l)
    {
        if(a[m]==x)
            return 1;
        else if(a[m]<x)
            { 
               f = m+1; m = f; 
            }
        else if(a[m]>x)  
            {
               l = m-1; m = l;
            }
    }
    return 0;
}
```